# Match at every second occurrence

Tags: regex

Is there a way to specify a regular expression to match every 2nd occurrence of a pattern in a string?

Examples

- searching for **a** against string **abcdabcd** should find one occurrence at position 5
- searching for **ab**  against string **abcdabcd** should find one occurrence at position 5
- searching for **dab**  against string **abcdabcd** should find no occurrences
- searching for **a** against string **aaaa** should find two occurrences at positions 2 and 4

Comment: Maybe I'm too picky but a regex will not "find" anything. It will only "match" a portion of your input string.  It's your programming language that offers you functions to match a string against a regex and return various information about the match (e.g. where it occured).

Comment: you're absolutely right, you are too picky ;)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Use capturing groups.

```
foo.*?(foo)
```

Use a regex like this to match all occurrences in a string. Every returned match will contain a second occurrence as its first captured group.

Here's an example that matches every second occurrence of `\d+` in Python using [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

```python
import re

input = '10 is less than 20, 5 is less than 10'
second_occurrences = re.findall(r'\d+.*?(\d+)', input)

print(second_occurrences)
```

Output:

```
['20', '10']
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I'm trying to match the second occurrence of a pattern, where the actual content of the second match is not the same as the first. I tried `|\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}.*?(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2})|` where the first occurrence could be `01/01/01` and the second could be `09/03/15` and I'm trying to grab `09/03/15`.

Comment: @AltimusPrime That regex works perfectly. `09/03/15` is the match's first subgroup.

Comment: This really needs a better explanation

Comment: I didnt understand it either :|

Comment: It's been 14 years coming but I've updated the answer to include a better explanation!

Answer (score 16):

Suppose the pattern you want is abc+d.  You want to match the second occurrence of this pattern in a string.

You would construct the following regex:

```
abc+d.*?(abc+d)
```

This would match strings of the form:   `<your-pattern>...<your-pattern>`.  Since we're using the reluctant qualifier *? we're safe that there cannot be another match of  between the two.  Using matcher groups which pretty much all regex implementations provide you would then retrieve the string in the bracketed group which is what you want.

Answer (score 7):

Would something like

```
(pattern.*?(pattern))*
```

work for you?

Edit:

The problem with this is that it uses the non-greedy operator `*?`, which can require an awful lot of backtracking along the string instead of just looking at each letter once. What this means for you is that this could be slow for large gaps.

Comment: I'm not sure, Patrick, I would say that the non-greedy operators can use less backtracking. It depends on the algorithm you use, of course, but to check "a.*a" you have to go up to the end of the string and try matching backward, for "a.*?a" you can try matching forward and stop when you do it.

Comment: Remo.D is right: non-greedy quantifiers don't increase backtracking, they eliminate it. (They may or may not be less efficient, but if they are it won't be because of backtracking.) But in this case, efficiency is irrelevant; as annakata pointed out, the quantifier has to be non-greedy for this approach to work.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using C#, you can either get all the matches at once (i.e. use `Regex.Matches()`, which returns a `MatchCollection`, and check the index of the item: `index % 2 != 0`).

If you want to find the occurrence to replace it, use one of the overloads of `Regex.Replace()` that uses a `MatchEvaluator` (e.g. `Regex.Replace(String, String, MatchEvaluator)`. Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "abcdabcd";

            // Replace *second* a with m

            string replacedString = Regex.Replace(
                input,
                "a",
                new SecondOccuranceFinder("m").MatchEvaluator);

            Console.WriteLine(replacedString);
            Console.Read();

        }

        class SecondOccuranceFinder
        {
            public SecondOccuranceFinder(string replaceWith)
            {
                _replaceWith = replaceWith;
                _matchEvaluator = new MatchEvaluator(IsSecondOccurance);
            }

            private string _replaceWith;

            private MatchEvaluator _matchEvaluator;
            public MatchEvaluator MatchEvaluator
            {
                get
                {
                    return _matchEvaluator;
                }
            }

            private int _matchIndex;
            public string IsSecondOccurance(Match m)
            {
                _matchIndex++;
                if (_matchIndex % 2 == 0)
                    return _replaceWith;
                else
                    return m.Value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Back references can find interesting solutions here. This regex:

```
([a-z]+).*(\1)
```

will find the longest repeated sequence.

This one will find a sequence of 3 letters that is repeated:

```
([a-z]{3}).*(\1)
```

Comment: This is slightly different take on the problem than the other answers, but you still need to make the quantifier non-greedy: /([a-z]+).*?(\1)/

Answer (score 0):

There's no "direct" way of doing so but you can specify the pattern twice as in: `a[^a]*a` that match up to the second "a".

The alternative is to use your programming language (perl? C#? ...) to match the first occurence and then the second one.

**EDIT**: I've seen other responded using the "non-greedy" operators which might be a good way to go, assuming you have them in your regex library!

Comment: /a[^a]*a/ finds the next two occurrences of 'a', but doesn't tell you where the second one is. Also, it only works when the base pattern is exactly one character long.