# Can't add multi-line text to list as one item

Tags: python, list, append, extend

I'm trying to make a list of scrapy crawl outputs by post for debugging purposes.

Here's my code:

```
post_list = []

with open('last_crawl_output.txt','r') as f:
    crawl_output = f.read()

# Find first 'referer' that indicates start of scrapy crawl AFTER initial crawl of search results page
iter = re.finditer("referer", crawl_output)
referer_list = [m.start(0) for m in iter]

# Find indicator of crawl finished.
iter2 = re.finditer("scrapy", crawl_output)
closing_list = [m.start(0) for m in iter2]

del referer_list[0]

pos1 = referer_list[0]

for pos1 in referer_list:
    # Get largest scrapy index after each referer index.
    pos2_index = bisect.bisect(closing_list, pos1)
    # Get post from positions.
    pos2 = closing_list[pos2_index+1]
    post = crawl_output[pos1:pos2-21]
```

I've also tried using `post_list.append(post)`, to no avail.

[edit]

Here's some sample output.

A string I want to add into `post_list` [here](http://dumptext.com/b3dZDWVt)

This is what I get instead. Here is `post_list` with the posts added: [output](http://dumptext.com/e1kkgBI2)

When I use insert, it separates by `\n`

Comment: Could you provide an example `referer_list` and `closing_list`? I'm also a bit confused about why you don't just write a regex that looks for both the start and end indicators in one go (e.g. `post_list = re.findall("referrer.*?scrapy", crawl_output)`).

Comment: @Blckknght I'm a total noob, so I'm only doing this the way I know how. I've updated the question. Does regex allow that in one line like you have?

Comment: I'm certain you can come up with a single regex that matches what you're looking for, though I suspect what I provided in my comment is not it (it ends with the first `scrapy` reference after the `referrer` is found, not the second).

Comment: @Blckknght I'm confused, because the regex your provided doesn't match anything in my output when inputted into regexr.com. I've found a clue [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589667/match-at-every-second-occurrence), but their regex matches both the first `foo` and the second `foo` after it. Please excuse my inexperience with regex.

Comment: I seem to have spelled "referer" differently than you (with an extra "r"). I suspect that's why it's not matching anything (rather than matching part of what you want). I think you could all of what you want with the pattern `"referer.*?scrapy.*?scrapy"` or something very similar.

Comment: @Blckknght Yes, I caught that in the beginning, but correcting still shows nothing. I've added a text dump to show some of the output I'm working with.

Comment: @Blckknght: 'referer' is a typo in the HTTP spec that can't be changed; that might be why it's spelled that way here.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to work my way around this list problem like this:

```
# Splits post by newline, adds to list
post_lines = post.split('\n')

# Add the words "Next Post" to differentiate each post. 
post_lines.append('Next Post')

# Print each line, and get perfect formatting.
for line in post_lines:
    print line
```

Answer (score 0):

A better solution would be to add posts to a dictionary instead. This keeps formatting and uses less code.

```
post_count = 0
post_dict = {}

for pos1 in referer_list:

    post_count += 1

    pos2_index = bisect.bisect(closing_list, pos1)
    pos2 = closing_list[pos2_index+1]

    post = crawl_output[pos1:pos2-21]

    post_dict[post_count] = post
```