# xslt 2.0 tokenize() regex - get substrings between each second occurence of space

Tags: regex, xslt, delimiter

I have an XML file where I have the following code:

```
 <RL>
<coordinates>7.53 -6.53 8.53 1.23 7.51 7021.13</coordinates>
 </RL>
```

There can be an infinite, but always even number of coordinates. Basically I want to split the strings before each second space so my that the plaintext output would be

```
coordinateTuple:7.53 -6.53
coordinateTuple:8.53 1.23 
coordinateTuple:7.51 7021.13
```

I've tried doing my research before asking, and I guess I should use the tokenize function, but I can't get the regex straight. My current code is

```
<xsl:for-each select="fn:tokenize(RL/coordinates,'\s.*?(\s)')">
    <xsl:text>coordinateTuple:</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```

which I thought would match every second occurence of a space (and it should, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/589699/4004531)), and therefore make the second space the delimiter for the tokenize() function. However, the actual output of this seems to be that it skips every second coordinate, but still gives me the last one:

```
coordinateTuple:7.53 
coordinateTuple:8.53
coordinateTuple:7.51 7021.13
```

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: You could try [`([-+\d.]+\s[-+\d.]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/bG1sP4/1)

Comment: I think you can try `\s(\S+)` with your approach.

Comment: Both of these don't work with the tokenize() approach (the regex in Jan's comment matches the substrings between every second space, not the actual second space, and therefore doesn't work for finding the delimiter I need. However, it works with the analyse-string method in Martin Honnens's answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `xsl:analyze-string`:

```
<xsl:template match="coordinates">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(\S+)\s+(\S+)">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('CoordinateTuple:', regex-group(1), ' ', regex-group(2), '&#10;')"/>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

I am not sure there is a way to tokenize only on every second whitespace sequence but you can certainly tokenize on each whitespace sequence and then process the first, third, fifth item and collect the second, fourth, sixth on that way:

```
    <xsl:variable name="numbers" select="tokenize(., '\s+')"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$numbers[position() mod 2 = 1]">
        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('CoordinateTuple:', ., ' ', $numbers[$pos * 2], '&#10;')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly! Although I'd still be interested if there's a way to do this with tokenize(), so I'll keep looking into this :)

Comment: @z_eb, I have some lines using `tokenize`.

Answer (score 2):

I think I would tokenize on space and then regroup:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="tokenize(., '\s+')" 
                    group-adjacent="(position()-1) idiv 2)">
  <xsl:value-of select="'CoordinateTuple:', current-group()"/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Comment: It should be `group-adjacent="(position() - 1) idiv 2"`, no?

Comment: Indeed it should. Fixed.