# Regex pattern not capturing the second occurrence of the match

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the string:

```
Error: heroku 6.14.38 is already installed
To upgrade to 7.7.1, run `brew upgrade heroku`
```

I'm doing `.slice(/([\d+\.]+)/)` and it's giving me the `6.14.38`, but not `7.7.1`.

How can I also get it?

Comment: [I can't reproduce the issue](https://regex101.com/r/nJBIAB/2). Let's see your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Match at every second occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589667/match-at-every-second-occurrence)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-scan) method:

```
str = "Error: heroku 6.14.38 is already installed
To upgrade to 7.7.1, run `brew upgrade heroku`"
puts(str.scan(/((?:\d+\.)+\d+)/))
```

Prints:

```
6.14.38
7.7.1
```

Comment: This might be what I'm looking for. `split` method returns a string, but I want an array

Comment: If the first line were `"Error: heroku 6.14.38 is already installed."` the following would be printed on successive lines:  `"6.14.38"`, `"."` and `"7.7.1"`. Incidentally, the period need not be escaped in a character class. Many characters that have special meaning in regex expressions lose there special special meaning and are treated as ordinary characters in character classes (`"ab."[/[.]/] #=> "."`, `"a$c"[/[$]/] #=> "$"` and so on).

Comment: Thank you @CarySwoveland, good point. I have corrected my answer to use expression `((?:\d+\.)+\d+)`.

Comment: That fixes that problem, though it still matches `"1.2.3.4.5.6"`. That may not be a problem, but it does not look like a Heroku version number. It's just as easy to write `/((?:\d\.){2}\d+/`, so why not?

Comment: Yeah, I was not aware of how a Heroku number looks like :)

Comment: Me neither; I was just going on the example. My comment is not so much about Heroku but to "tighten" regular expressions as much as possible. Aside: does your name refer to how you tip the scales?

Comment: You make a good point, but perhaps that Heroku number is a version number, which could in the future include more levels (more `.` and digits). The name refers to the book Unbearable Lightness of Being by Milan Kundera, read it a few years ago and loved it. Checked your profile by the way, I was actually in Victoria last year, lovely place!

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "Error: heroku 6.14.38 is already installed
To upgrade to 7.7.1, run `brew upgrade heroku`"

r = /
    \d{1,2}  # match one or two digits
    \.       # match decimal
    \d{1,2}  # match two digits
    \.       # match decimal
    \d{1,2}  # match two digits
    .+?      # match any number of characters, lazily
    \K       # discard match so far
    \d{1,2}  # match one or two digits
    \.       # match decimal
    \d{1,2}  # match two digits
    \.       # match decimal
    \d{1,2}  # match two digits
    /xm      # free-spacing regex definition and multiline modes

str[r]
  #=> "7.7.1"
```